# Textmate files opening in Dashcode

Tags: dashcode

How do you stop making Textmate open up files in Dashcode? I just want it to render as a tab/new window.

Answer (score 0):

Your tags are wrong, this has nothing to do with html5 or css3. And I think it has little to do with TextMate.

I had all my .js files assigned to DashCode, the following solved the issue.

Select one of the files in the Finder and hit <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to bring up the Informations window.

There is a "Open with:" select, choose TextMate, click on the button below and complete the process.

Do it with all the offending file types, quit and relaunch your session (to be safe).

Do you still have the same problem?